# How to add width to an element using jquery each function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, progress-bar

I want to build a loading bar effect using two seperate divs inside each other. I got it all positioned and all that but how can I make one of them increase its width from %1 to %100 with transition? I want it to be filled in 10 sec.

Thanks.

```
 <div class="loading-container">

            <div class="outside-loading"></div>
            <div class="inside-loading"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple with jQuery [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) which you can customize for step or  easing and also use callbacks for start or complete as needed

```js
$('.outside-loading').animate({width: '100%'}, 3000);// using 3 sec for demo
```

```css
.outside-loading {
  background: blue;
  width: 0;
  height: .5em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loading-container">
  <div class="outside-loading"></div>
  <div class="inside-loading"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this works perfect! and also I am making this for slider and it slides after 10 sec and I changed loading animation from 3 to 10. It slides but when I come back to previous slider, animation doesn't reset. how can I fix this? thanks again.

Comment: Use complete callback to reset width

Comment: I am currently using swiper.js and I am going to use this bar to make it look like an loading bar, is there a way to callback when slided to other image?

Comment: Use the events api of swiper to start and reset your progress bar

Comment: Probably want to look at using jQuery `stop()` also..see docs

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla Javascript**

Create a function and increase the width with your set interval function. Add a conditional that checks if the width is 100% and if it is, then clear the interval. I also moved the divs within each other and set the display of the inner span tag to inline-block...

You can also target the elements `textContent` and display the widths progress in percent as well...

```js
var i = 0;


function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("inside-loading");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 100);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem[0].style.width = width + "%";
        elem[0].textContent = width + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}

move();
```

```css
.outside-loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.inside-loading {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<div class="loading-container">
  <div class="outside-loading">
    <span class="inside-loading">
        
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```